# Как отправить письмо без логина,пароля и шифрования?

Tags: golang, email, smtp

Нужно реализовать сервис отправки писем (рекомендуемый способ отправки не работает).

При попытке отправить стандартным способом выдаёт ошибку:

> certificate signed by unknown authority

P.S. отключить шифрование TLS не помогло. =( Подобный сервис написанный на Java - работает без проблем!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/smtp"
)

func main() {

    from := "john.doe@example.com"

    user := nil
    password := nil

    to := []string{
        "roger.roe@example.com",
    }

    addr := "smtp.mailtrap.io:25"
    host := "smtp.mailtrap.io"

    msg := []byte("From: john.doe@example.com\r\n" +
        "To: roger.roe@example.com\r\n" +
        "Subject: Test mail\r\n\r\n" +
        "Email body\r\n")

    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", user, password, host)

    err := smtp.SendMail(addr, auth, from, to, msg)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Email sent successfully")
}
```

Comment: Распечатайте установленные корневые сертификаты: https://go.dev/play/p/WlY98FyL7k7
В списке должен быть сертификат `C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority`. Если такого нет, нужно добавить.

Comment: @PakUula
А есть возможность сделать это без установки сертификатов?

Comment: Исходный код для [`smtp.SendMail`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/net/smtp/smtp.go;l=338) проверяет наличие поддержки TLS в сервере и автоматически переключается в режим с шифрованием. При установлении зашифрованного канала используются сертификаты. Альтернатива - разбить сессию SMTP по шагам: `smtp.Helo()`, затем `smtp.Auth()`, после чего можно отсылать письмо: `smtp.Mail()`, `smtp.Recpt`, `smtp.Data()`, `smtp.Close()`

Comment: Но я полагаю, где-то между `Auth()` и `Mail()` сервер выдаст ошибку 538 `RLS Required` и отвалится.

Comment: Спасибо, @PakUula !

Answer (score 2):

Я немного подумал о вашем вопросе и понял, что к Go он никак не относится.

SMTP сервер, который отправляет почту без логина и паролья -- это крайне редкий зверь по нашим временам. Такие сервера позволяют рассылать письма в любых количествах (читай - спамить), посылать письма от имени любого отправителя из любого домена (читай - спуфить) и с произвольной информацией об IP адресе отправителя (читай - затирать следы). Поэтому с середины двухтысячных с такими серверами начали бороться. Если такой сервер становится известным, его IP адрес быстро банят на всех больших почтовых сервисах и перестают принимать от такого сервера письма.

Поэтому среди хакеров даже бытовал определённый бизнес - взломать компьютер, подключенный к сети, и установить в него почтовый сервер, чтобы рассылать спам и всякую левую почту на заказ.

Поэтому я вижу два пути как отправлять почту без логина и пароля.

1. Узнать у знакомых хакеров адресок-другой подпольных серверов.
2. Поставить свой собственный почтовый сервер, настроить SPF и DKIM, и рассылать через него. Если не наглеть, то какое-то время он продержится и не попадёт во всякие черные списки, откуда почтовые сервисы узнают о скомпрометированных или спамерских почтовых релеях.

Есть, на самом деле, ещё один способ. Все, вот прям такие все-все, почтовые сервисы представляют почтовые сервера без аутентификации. Правда, есть одно НО - эти сервера не пересылают почту дальше. Они лишь принимают почту для тех доменов, которые поддерживаются сервисом. Соответственно, перед тем, как отправить почту, нужно сначала узнать адрес почтового сервера получателя.

Вот как такая программа могла быть устроена для отправки в Gmail:

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "net/smtp"
)

func main() {

    mx, _ := net.LookupMX("google.com")
    srv := mx[0].Host

    email := `Subject: Test of email
From: <pakuula@example.net>
Message-ID: <deadbeef-foo-bar-baz@smtp.example.org>

Hello, world!
`
    err := smtp.SendMail(
        srv+":25",
        nil,
        "pakuula@example.net",
        []string{"pakuula@gmail.com"},
        []byte(email),
    )
    if err != nil {
        println("SMTP error: ", err.Error())
    } else {
        println("Message sent")
    }
}
```

Но так тоже не сработает. Ибо подобных умников развелось премногие тыщи. И нынче почтовые сервисы проверяют входящую почту на всякие атрибуты:

- SPF: в DNS записи для домена отправителя должна быть TXT запись, начинающаяся с `v=spf1`, где указаны доменные имена и/или адреса почтовых серверов, с которых рассылается почта для данного домена. В частности, для данного примера использован домен `example.net`. У него SPF запись вот какая: `v=spf1 -all`, то есть нет ни одного доверенного сервера для отправки почты. Поэтому любой вменяемый почтовый сервер даст отлуп с номером 550. Поэтому вам нужно зарегать свой домен и указать IP адрес, с которого пуляет письмами ваш спам-бот, в качестве доверенного.
- DKIM: сервера-получатели хотят подтверждение, что письмо отправлено именно тем, кто указан в поле `From`. Для этого серверы-отправители, спросив у пользователя логин-пароль, должны отсылать от имени логина только те письма, в которых в поле From указан именно логин пользователя. А для предотвращения всяческих манипуляций и replay-атак они включают в письмо цифровую подпись заголовков. Например свзяку полей Date,To, From, Subject, Message-ID. Публичный ключ для верификации доступен из DNS. Пиьсьма без DKIM заголовков крупные сервисы отвергают.

Так что не такое это простое дело - отсылать письма без логина и пароля.

**UPDATE**

К вашему вопросу. Предлагаю добавить сертификат сервера в пул доверенных. Для этого его сначала нужно раздобыть. Утилита `openssl s_client` умеет подключаться к SMTP и запускать `STARTTLS`:

```
openssl s_client -connect <server>:25 -starttls smtp -showcerts
```

В распечатеке будут сертификаты в формате PEM, что-то вроде

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGUDCCBTigAwIBAgIQCU+8RgcTHyNmHIAFkj6bxjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBe
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
...
j6Mh14tp4+aVnDPHlbUnKePlUQxxnhXSpFsLP2VQqZ/BxG4v8k+N+eaNT4u5hc5t
ARLUqG/WO0xvPdPJ7eRYFajtzxhOiOLCyS+w/RI8Qr08O3Xn
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Сертификат точно должен быть, может быть несколько, если цепочка сертификатов насчитывает более двух сертификатов. Скопируйте сертификаты в свою программу и добавьте в пул.

Все сертификаты могут быть заведены в одну константу типа `string`. Пул системных сертификатов даёт функция `x509.SystemCertPool`. Метод `AppendCertsFromPEM` парсит строковую константу и загружает сертификаты в пул.

```
const mail_certs = `
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGUDCCBTigAwIBAgIQCU+8RgcTHyNmHIAFkj6bxjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBe
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
...
j6Mh14tp4+aVnDPHlbUnKePlUQxxnhXSpFsLP2VQqZ/BxG4v8k+N+eaNT4u5hc5t
ARLUqG/WO0xvPdPJ7eRYFajtzxhOiOLCyS+w/RI8Qr08O3Xn
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEizCCA3OgAwIBAgIQBUb+GCP34ZQdo5/OFMRhczANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBh
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
...
O9PuiHMKrC6V6mgi0s2sa/gbXlPCD9Z24XUMxJElwIVTDuKB0Q4YMMlnpN/QChJ4
B0AFsQ+DU0NCO+f78Xf7
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

func main() {
    certs, err := x509.SystemCertPool()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if !certs.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(mail_certs)) {
        panic("failed to add certificate")
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: SMTP сервер, который отправляет почту без логина и пароля есть. Он находится внутри корпоративной сети. 
Есть сервис(написанный на Java) который отправляет через этот сервер письма.
Задача стоит в реализации подобного сервиса для отправки писем на языке Go.

Comment: @Alex В корпоративной среде используется корпоративная (читай, Active Directory или аналогичная) система авторизации и аутентификации.

Comment: @Alex быть такого не может. Как в этом случае сервер аутентифицирует отправителя и подписывает DKIM? Я бы предположил, что где-то за кулисами выполняется аутентификация через Active Directory

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Привязка идёт по IP.

Comment: @Alex я добавил как получить сертификат и добавить в TLS.

Comment: @PakUula Спасибо за дополнение. Но это решение не подходит так как нет прав на установку сертификатов. Системные администраторы запрещают вносить изменения на машинах где крутится сервис.

Comment: @Alex я имел в виду установить сертификат в клиентское приложение. Сначала добываете сертификат сервера (можете у админов спросить), а затем в клиенте перед отправкой почты вызываете `certs.AppendCertsFromPEM`

Comment: @PakUula хорошо. Попробую. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Может попробовать использовать для отправки писем Python? Делюсь статьей - https://codeby.net/threads/otpravljaem-pochtu-s-pomoschju-python-sozdadim-prostoj-klass-dlja-otpravki-soobschenij.80328/ , автор рассказывать как создать класс для отправки писем, в питоне отправка писем идет из коробки, поэтому нечего не нужно устанавливать.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Спасибо, но нужен компилируемый язык. Текущее решение уже работает на Java. Хотим сделать компактное решение. Подойдут языки : Go, Rust, C++ .

Comment: На Go пока не получается реализовать решение так как Go не умеет отправлять почту без TLS.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть связана с тем, что ваш почтовый сервер использует цепочку сертификатов, которая не может быть валидирована указанным клиентом. Другая возможная причина может быть та, что сертификат, используемый вашим сервером, не является действительным или был удален из хранилища сертификатов на клиенте.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, вам может потребоваться предоставить серверу свой собственный файл сертификата, который будет использоваться для валидации цепочки сертификатов. Вы также можете рассмотреть возможность использования другого почтового клиента, который может быть более совместим с вашим почтовым сервером. Поэтому рекомендуется обратиться к документации вашего почтового сервера

Для того, чтобы подключить свой сертификат, вы можете использовать функцию tls.LoadX509KeyPair, чтобы загрузить свой сертификат и ключ в виде структур tls.Certificate. Затем вы можете использовать эту структуру в качестве аргумента для функции tls.Dial вместо указанной структуры smtp.PlainAuth.

Вот пример того, как это может выглядеть:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/smtp"
)

func main() {
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert.pem", "key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    config := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }

    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "smtp.mailtrap.io:25", config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    client, err := smtp.NewClient(conn, "smtp.mailtrap.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := client.Auth(smtp.PlainAuth("", "user", "password", "smtp.mailtrap.io")); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := client.Mail("john.doe@example.com"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := client.Rcpt("roger.roe@example.com"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    w, err := client.Data()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    msg := []byte("From: john.doe@example.com\r\n" +
        "To: roger.roe@example.com\r\n" +
        "Subject: Test mail\r\n\r\n" +
        "Email body\r\n")

    if _, err := w.Write(msg); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := client.Quit(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Email sent successfully")
}
```

Обратите внимание, что этот код уже не использует функцию smtp.SendMail, а вместо этого использует низкоуровневые функции из пакета smtp, чтобы напрямую управлять процессом отправки писем.